# Without recompiling, force program and associated DLLs to load in lower memory?

Tags: windows, winapi

Customer was using program on Windows 7. Worked fine for him. Then, Windows 7 support went away and so he had to install on Windows 10. On Windows 10, he's experiencing a crash. Luckily, we were able to duplicate--it's in a portion that hardly anybody uses... It's pointer truncation from old code base assuming 32-bit pointers. Easy to fix.

However, it will probably be a while before we can get the customer an update or hotfix to address the issue.

I'd like to find a hack, if you will, to support the customer.

Is it possible with registry settings or some other hackery to force the program and our DLLs to load in lower memory (what fits on a 32-bit machine) so that the customer won't be bothered with this crash until we can get a fix to him?

Comment: think you need rebuild your dll and fix errors, no better solution

Comment: Use editbin.exe, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150709-00/?p=45181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, following the advice of @HansPassant, I used editbin.exe to edit the large address aware and high entropy va values in the EXE headers. This did clear up the crash.

```
editbin /largeaddressaware:no /highentropyva:no some.exe
```

I doubt this will be used, however.

The issue had already been fixed in our upcoming release--whenever that may be. Our current engineering manager decided to address some technical debt that the old hadn't and insisted that the codebase of more than 25+ years could have no warning messages when compiled. Some of us had always tried to do that anyways, but others not so much. "It compiles..., what do you mean???"

The problematic code was in something that was actually originally in the 16-bit Windows product and a piece of code customers rarely touched. I imagine that the customer that upgraded to Windows 10 might have also upgraded his machine as well and might have had more than 4GB of memory. Whatever the case, it's important to look at warnings and fix them.

Comment: Hi, don't forget to mark your answer to end this thread, other community members can benefit from it. [How to mark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You could use rebase.exe to change the default load addresses of all the code files but if your program uses any heap memory you are likely out of luck, there is no way to change where windows chooses to put that and those addresses are very likely to be greater than 32-bit.